# Animated Menu not Transitioning

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to animate a vertical open and close for my mobile menu using Tailwindcss in a React environment and can't seem to figure out why I am seeing the menu show and hide based on the state boolean, but not seeing the transitions based on the classes I am using. Is there something off with the classes?

**Animated Classes:**

*Container*

```
<div
  class="container flex flex-col mx-auto lg:hidden transition-transform transform translate-x-0 ease-out duration-500"
  id="mobile-menu"
>
```

*List of links*

```
   <ul class="flex flex-col duration-300 ease-out sm:transition-none space-y-5 pt-5 lg:pt-0 lg:space-y-0 lg:flex-row lg:space-x-10">
```

**Full Code:**

```
<div
  class="container flex flex-col mx-auto lg:hidden transition-transform transform translate-x-0 ease-out duration-500"
  id="mobile-menu"
>
  <div class="flex flex-row">
    <ul class="flex flex-col duration-300 ease-out sm:transition-none space-y-5 pt-5 lg:pt-0 lg:space-y-0 lg:flex-row lg:space-x-10">
      <div class="relative">
        <li class="flex flex-row">
          <a href="#" class="flex">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke-width="1.5"
              stroke="currentColor"
              class="w-6 h-6"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M12 6.042A8.967 8.967 0 006 3.75c-1.052 0-2.062.18-3 .512v14.25A8.987 8.987 0 016 18c2.305 0 4.408.867 6 2.292m0-14.25a8.966 8.966 0 016-2.292c1.052 0 2.062.18 3 .512v14.25A8.987 8.987 0 0018 18a8.967 8.967 0 00-6 2.292m0-14.25v14.25"
              ></path>
            </svg>
            <p class="ml-2 mr-2">Topics</p>
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke-width="1.5"
              stroke="currentColor"
              class="w-6 h-6"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <div class="hidden">
          <ul class="flex flex-col px-3 divide-y">
            <li class="block p-4">
              <a href="/tag/data/">Data</a>
            </li>
            <li class="block p-4">
              <a href="/tag/business/">Business</a>
            </li>
            <li class="block p-4">
              <a href="/tag/technology/">Technology</a>
            </li>
            <li class="block p-4">
              <a href="/tag/marketing/">Marketing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="block p-4">
              <a href="/tag/thoughts/">Thoughts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="block p-4">
              <a href="/tag/programming/">Programming</a>
            </li>
            <li class="block p-4">
              <a href="/tags/">All Topics</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <li class="flex flex-row">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke-width="1.5"
          stroke="currentColor"
          class="w-6 h-6"
        >
          <path
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
            d="M20.25 14.15v4.25c0 1.094-.787 2.036-1.872 2.18-2.087.277-4.216.42-6.378.42s-4.291-.143-6.378-.42c-1.085-.144-1.872-1.086-1.872-2.18v-4.25m16.5 0a2.18 2.18 0 00.75-1.661V8.706c0-1.081-.768-2.015-1.837-2.175a48.114 48.114 0 00-3.413-.387m4.5 8.006c-.194.165-.42.295-.673.38A23.978 23.978 0 0112 15.75c-2.648 0-5.195-.429-7.577-1.22a2.016 2.016 0 01-.673-.38m0 0A2.18 2.18 0 013 12.489V8.706c0-1.081.768-2.015 1.837-2.175a48.111 48.111 0 013.413-.387m7.5 0V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0013.5 3h-3a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v.894m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0M12 12.75h.008v.008H12v-.008z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
        <p class="ml-2">
          <a href="/portfolio/">Portfolio</a>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="flex flex-row">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke-width="1.5"
          stroke="currentColor"
          class="w-6 h-6"
        >
          <path
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
            d="M15.75 6a3.75 3.75 0 11-7.5 0 3.75 3.75 0 017.5 0zM4.501 20.118a7.5 7.5 0 0114.998 0A17.933 17.933 0 0112 21.75c-2.676 0-5.216-.584-7.499-1.632z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
        <p class="ml-2">
          <a href="/about/">About</a>
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ul
    class="flex pt-5 lg:pt-0 lg:space-y-0 justify-around lg:space-x-10"
    id="nav-social-links"
  >
    <li>
      <a
        title="Linkedin"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener"
        href="https://www.linkedin.com"
      >
        <svg
          role="img"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          class="w-5 h-5 text-midnight-500"
        >
          <path d="M20.447 20.452h-3.554v-5.569c0-1.328-.027-3.037-1.852-3.037-1.853 0-2.136 1.445-2.136 2.939v5.667H9.351V9h3.414v1.561h.046c.477-.9 1.637-1.85 3.37-1.85 3.601 0 4.267 2.37 4.267 5.455v6.286zM5.337 7.433c-1.144 0-2.063-.926-2.063-2.065 0-1.138.92-2.063 2.063-2.063 1.14 0 2.064.925 2.064 2.063 0 1.139-.925 2.065-2.064 2.065zm1.782 13.019H3.555V9h3.564v11.452zM22.225 0H1.771C.792 0 0 .774 0 1.729v20.542C0 23.227.792 24 1.771 24h20.451C23.2 24 24 23.227 24 22.271V1.729C24 .774 23.2 0 22.222 0h.003z"></path>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a
        href="https://www.github.com/"
        title="Github"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener"
      >
        <svg
          role="img"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          class="w-5 h-5 text-midnight-500"
        >
          <path d="M12 .297c-6.63 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.303 3.438 9.8 8.205 11.385.6.113.82-.258.82-.577 0-.285-.01-1.04-.015-2.04-3.338.724-4.042-1.61-4.042-1.61C4.422 18.07 3.633 17.7 3.633 17.7c-1.087-.744.084-.729.084-.729 1.205.084 1.838 1.236 1.838 1.236 1.07 1.835 2.809 1.305 3.495.998.108-.776.417-1.305.76-1.605-2.665-.3-5.466-1.332-5.466-5.93 0-1.31.465-2.38 1.235-3.22-.135-.303-.54-1.523.105-3.176 0 0 1.005-.322 3.3 1.23.96-.267 1.98-.399 3-.405 1.02.006 2.04.138 3 .405 2.28-1.552 3.285-1.23 3.285-1.23.645 1.653.24 2.873.12 3.176.765.84 1.23 1.91 1.23 3.22 0 4.61-2.805 5.625-5.475 5.92.42.36.81 1.096.81 2.22 0 1.606-.015 2.896-.015 3.286 0 .315.21.69.825.57C20.565 22.092 24 17.592 24 12.297c0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12"></path>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a
        title="RSS"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener"
        href="https://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/https://www.test.com/rss/"
      >
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          class="w-5 h-5 text-midnight-600 dark:text-white"
          viewBox="0 0 22 22"
        >
          <circle cx="6.18" cy="17.82" r="2.18"></circle>
          <path d="M4 4.44v2.83c7.03 0 12.73 5.7 12.73 12.73h2.83c0-8.59-6.97-15.56-15.56-15.56zm0 5.66v2.83c3.9 0 7.07 3.17 7.07 7.07h2.83c0-5.47-4.43-9.9-9.9-9.9z"></path>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>;
```